# Prelude Syntax-Checker

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, balanced-string, syntax

[Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude) is an esoteric programming language, which has very few, but unusual, restrictions on what constitutes a valid program. Any block of printable ASCII text ("block" meaning that lines of printable ASCII are separated by newlines - 0x0A) is valid provided that:

- Every (vertical) column of text contains at most one of `(` and `)`.
- Ignoring their vertical position, the `(` and `)` are balanced, that is, each `(` is paired with exactly one `)` to the right of it, and vice versa.

Write a program or function which, given a string containing printable ASCII and newlines, determines if it constitutes a valid Prelude program. You may take input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument. The result may be returned or printed to STDOUT, using any two *fixed* [truthy/falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/8478) values of your choice.

You must *not* assume that the input is rectangular.

This is code golf, so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

### Examples

The following are **valid** Prelude programs (in fact, they're even *real* Prelude programs):

```
?1-(v  #1)-             
1   0v ^(#    0)(1+0)#)!
    (#)  ^#1-(0 #
```

```
1(#  1) v #  - 1+)
    vv (##^v^+
? v-(0 # ^   #)
?
  1+              1-!
```

And here are a number of inputs, all of which are **invalid**:

```
#(#(##)##)##(
)##(##(##)#)#
```

```
#(#)
)###
```

```
#(##
(##)
```

```
(##)
(#)#
```

```
(##)
(###
```

```
#(#)
(##)
```

```
#(#)
###)
```

```
#()#
()##
```

```
#(#)##
###
###(#)
```

Comment: Does Prelude have comments which could block out a close paren?

Comment: @Alex No. The above rules are really all there is to deciding whether a program is valid or not.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Rule 1 - "Every column of text contains at most one of ( and )"; Example 1, line 2: "1   0v ^(#    0)(1+0)#)!" --> I see 3 `)` and 2 `(`. Shouldn't it be only 1 per line?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you're looking at lines/rows, not columns. There may be only one `(` or `)` per *vertical* column.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That isn't specified in the question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel ["column"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/column) is usually understood to refer to vertical lines (especially in the context of grids). I've clarified it anyway, though.

Comment: Are `)(` and `)()(` valid programs?

Comment: @Blackhole No, those parentheses aren't correctly balanced. "... each `(` and be paired with exactly one `)` **to the right of it**, and vice versa."

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Can we assume the input has a newline at the end?

Comment: @Omar yes you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
qN/z_{_"()"--W<},,\s:Q,{)Q/({_')/,\'(/,-}:T~\sT0e>+z+}/!
```

Too long, can be golfed a lot. Explanation to be added once I golf it.

**Brief explanation**

There are two checks in the code:

- First filter checks that each column as at most 1 bracket. The final output of the filter is the number of columns with more than 1 brackets.
- Second we convert the input into column major format and then split it on each index into two parts.

  - In each of these two parts, (`Number of "(" - Number of ")"`) should be complimenting each other. So when you add them up, it should result to 0. Any part that fails this property makes the whole input have non matching brackets.
  - I also have to make sure that "(" are to the left of ")". This means that the value of `Number of "(" - Number of ")"` cannot be negative for the right side block.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2Fz_%7B_%22()%22--W%3C%7D%2C%2C%5Cs%3AQ%2C%7B)Q%2F(%7B_')%2F%2C%5C'(%2F%2C-%7D%3AT~%5CsT0e%3E%2Bz%2B%7D%2F!&input=%23(%23(%23%23)%23%23)%23%23(%0A)%23%23(%23%23(%23%23)%23)%23)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>128</s> <s>119</s> 105 bytes

```py
def F(p):
 v=n=1
 for r in map(None,*p.split("\n")):A,B=map(r.count,"()");n+=B-A;v*=n<2>A+B
 return n*v>0
```

Did you know that you can [map None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length) in Python 2?

### Explanation

We want to start by transposing the Prelude so that columns become rows. Usually we would do this with `zip`, but since `zip` truncates to the shortest row length and `itertools.zip_longest` is far too long for code-golf, it seems like there's no short way to do what we want...

Except for mapping `None`:

```
>>> print map(None,*[[1,2,3],[4],[5,6]])
[(1, 4, 5), (2, None, 6), (3, None, None)]
```

Unfortunately (or rather, fortunately for all non-golf purposes), this only works in Python 2.

As for `n` and `v`:

- `n` acts like a stack, counting `1 - <number of unmatched '(' remaining>`. For every `(` we see we subtract 1, and for every `)` we see we add 1. Hence if `n >= 2` at any point, then we've seen too many `)`s and the program is invalid. If `n` doesn't finish on 1, then we have at least one unmatched `(` remaining.
- `v` checks validity, and starts at 1. If the program is ever invalid (`n >= 2` or `A+B >= 2`), then `v` becomes 0 to mark invalidity.

Hence if the program is valid, then by the end we must have `n = 1, v = 1`. If the program is invalid, then by the end we must either have `v = 0`, or `v = 1, n <= 0`. Therefore validity can be succinctly expressed as `n*v>0`.

*(Thanks to @feersum for a multitude of good suggestions which took off 14 bytes!)*

### Previous, more readable submission:

```
def F(p):
 p=map(None,*p.split("\n"));v=n=0
 for r in p:R=r.count;A=R("(");B=R(")");n+=A-B;v|=A+B>1or n<0
 return n<1>v
```

Comment: That's an insane use of `map`...

Comment: 119 -> 106 `def F(p):        v=n=3        for r in map(None,*p.split("\n")):A,B=map(R.count,"()");n+=A-B;v*=n>2>A+B        return n*v==9`

Comment: @feersum Thanks! I'd been trying to change the `or` into comparison chaining, but I didn't think of changing `|=` into `*=`. Took off another byte though, by making things even *more* backwards :)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 64 bytes

Input is a string with a trailing newline. Output is 0 or 1.

```
(0=(1<|s)s+[:(|@{:+(0>])s)[:+/\]s=.+/@:)@(1 _1 0{~[:'()'&i.];.2)
```

Example usage

```
   ]in=.'#(#)##',LF,'###',LF,'###(#)',LF
#(#)##
###
###(#)

   ((0=(1<|s)s+[:(|@{:+(0>])s)[:+/\]s=.+/@:)@(1 _1 0{~[:'()'&i.];.2)) in
0
```

The method is the following

- cut input at newlines and put into a matrix   `];.2`
- map `(` / `)` / `anything else` into `1` / `-1` / `0`   `1 _1 0{~[:'()'&i.]`
- define an `s=.+/@:` adverb which added to a verb sums the verbs array output
- add values in columns   `]s`

  - check positive `()` balance in every prefix   `[:(0>])s)[:+/\]`
  - check equal `()` balance in the whole list (i.e. in the last prefix)   `|@{:@]`
- add abs(values) in columns and check every element for a max value of 1   `(1<|s)s`
- as all the previous checks yielded positive at failure we add them up and compare to 0 to get the validity of the input   `0=]`

Answer (score 2):

## J, 56 bytes

```
3 :'*/0<: ::0:(+/\*:b),-.|b=.+/+.^:_1]0|:''()''=/];.2 y'
```

That is an anonymous function accepting a string with a trailing newline and returning 0 or 1. Reading from right to left:

- `];.2 y`, as in the other J submission, cuts the string `y` at all occurrences of its last character (which is why the input needs a trailing newline) and makes a rectangular matrix whose rows are the pieces, padded with spaces if necessary.
- `'()'=/` compares every character in that matrix first with `(` and then with `)` returning a list of two 0-1 matrices.
- `+.^:_1]0|:` turns that list of two matrices into a single matrix of complex numbers. So far the program turns every `(` in the input into a 1, every `)` into i, and every other character into 0.
- `b=.+/` assigns the sum of the rows of that complex matrix to `b`.
- `-.|b` makes a list of 1-|z| for every z in `b`. The condition that every column contain at most a single parenthesis translates to all these numbers 1-|z| being nonnegative.
- `+/\*:b` is the vector of running sums of the squares of the numbers in `b`. If every column does contain at most one parenthesis, the squares of the numbers in `b` are all 0, 1 or -1. The `,` concatenates this vector with the vector of 1-|z|'s.
- now all we need to do is test that the entries of our concatenated vector `v` are nonnegative reals numbers, this is almost `*/0<:v`, except that that causes an error if some entries of `v` are not real, so we replace `<:` with `<: ::0:` which just returns 0 in case of error.

Comment: Great ideas with the complex numbers but you also need to check if `0={:+/\*:b` because e.g. `(` isn't valid.

Comment: Oh, you're right, @randomra, I forgot!

Comment: `0=(-|)v` is 2 bytes shorter for checking non-negative reals. (Let's beat CJam! :P)

Comment: Oh, and `inv` instead of `^:_1`  saves another byte.

Comment: `(-.@|,+/\@:*:)+/+.inv` saves 1 more and might help with the balance check (with `0={:`)

Comment: Back to 56 (with balance checking): `3 :'*/0=({:,]-|)(-.@|,+/\@:*:)+/+.inv]0|:''()''=/];.2 y'`.