# Is it L-convex?

Tags: code-golf, array, geometry, decision-problem

### Background

A [polyomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) is called *L-convex*, if it's possible to travel from any tile to any other tile by an L-shaped path, that is, a path that goes in the cardinal directions and changes direction at most once.
For example, the polyomino of `1`s in the figure

```
0 0 1 1 1 0

1 1 1 1 0 0

1 1 0 0 0 0
```

is not L-convex, since both L-shaped paths from the bottom left `1` to the top right `1` contain a `0`:

```
0>0>1>1>1 0
^       ^
1 1 1 1 0 0
^       ^
1>1>0>0>0 0
```

However, the polyomino of `1`s in this figure is L-convex:

```
0 1 1 1 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1

0 1 1 0 0 0
```

### Input

Your input is a 2D array of bits in the native format of your language, or as a newline-delimited string if our language lacks arrays.
It is guaranteed to contain at least one `1`.

### Output

Your output shall be a truthy value if the set of `1`s is an L-convex polyomino, and a falsy value if not.
These outputs must be consistent: you must output the same truthy value for all L-convex inputs, and the same falsy value for others.
Note that a disconnected set of `1`s (which is not a polyomino) results in a falsy output.

### Rules and Scoring

You can write either a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

### Test Cases

These test cases should work also if you rotate or reflect the arrays, or add rows of `0`s to any borders.

```
False instances
01
10

111
101
111

1101
1111
1110

1100
1000
0011

01100
11110
01110
00110

011000
011110
001111

True instances
1

01
11

010
111
010

001
011
111

11100
11110
01100
01000

011000
011000
111100
111111
001000
```

Comment: Very nice challenge, I enjoyed it=)

Comment: About input: it a *newline-delimited string* allowed, *if our language **does not** lack arrays* ?

Comment: @edc65 (Sorry, been off the grid for a couple of days.) Sure, that's allowed too, it's just badly worded on my part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Snails](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47495/30688), <s>45</s> 24

```
&
!{\1t\1!{o\1,nf\1,!.!~
```

Right after posting my initial solution, I realized there was a much better way. The original program traveled around the square formed by the paths between two `1`s, testing for the presence of a 0 in each pair of sides. It also had to have a special case for straight line paths. The new version starts by teleporting from one `1` to the other, and testing for the absence of a straight or L-shaped path of `1`s back to the start.

Comment: OMG!! Is there an online interpreter where we could play around with this?

Comment: @flawr You can build it from source with the source code [here](https://github.com/feresum/PMA).

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, 182 bytes

Idea: Repeat for every `1` in the polyomino matrix:

- Create new matrix with only the given `1` but the rest zero.
- for every `1` in this new matrix (repeat until nothing changes anymore)

  - add `1` as neighbours in x direction if there are `1` as neighbours in the polynomio
- for every `1` in this new matrix (repeat until nothing changes anymore)

  - add `1` as neighbours in x direction if there are `1` as neighbours in the polynomio

Now `1` in the new matrix should cover all `1` in the polynomio-matrix that are reachable from the given starting point by first going in x-direction and then in y-direction. Now we can repeat the same process but with first going into y-direction and then in x-direction. Now every `1` of the polyomino matrix should be reached at once or both times. If not, then we have found a position in the polynomio matrix that cannot be reached from every other position by an `L`-path.

Golfed:

```
function r=f(a);[i,j,b]=find(a);N=nnz(i);r=1;for k=1:N;K=1:3;for l=1:2;c=b;b=a*0;b(i(k),j(k))=1;for z=1:2*N; b=conv2(b+0,K,'s')&a;if z==N;K=K';end;end;end;r=r*all(b(:)|c(:)>=a(:));end
```

With comments:

```
function r=codegolf_L_convex(a);
%a=[0,1;1,1];
[i,j,b]=find(a);%b just needs to be initialized, does not really mattter
N=nnz(i);%number of ones in the matrix
r=1;%return value
for k=1:N;%go throu all '1' in the matrix
    %expand that pixel in x dir:
    K=1:3;%convolution kernel (just three positive values needed)
    for l=1:2;%first horizontal->vertical then vertical->horizontal
        c=b;%backup for considering both runs
        b=a*0;
        b(i(k),j(k))=1; %set the seed
        for z=1:2*N;     
            b=conv2(b+0,K,'s')&a; %expand the seed horizontally (or vertically for the second half) but only within the polyomino
            if z==N;
                K=K'; %change horizontal/vertical 
            end;
        end;
    end;
    r=r*all(b(:)|c(:)>=a(:));%check whether we can really reach every point
end
```

Test cases script:

```
disp('all false -------------');
a=[0,1;1,0];
f(a)
a=[1,1,1;1,0,1;1,1,1];
f(a)
a=[1,1,0,1;1,1,1,1;1,1,1,0];
f(a)
a=[1,1,0,0;1,0,0,0;0,0,1,1];
f(a)
a=[0,1,1,0,0;1,1,1,1,0;0,1,1,1,0;0,0,1,1,0];
f(a)
a=[0,1,1,0,0,0;0,1,1,1,1,0;0,0,1,1,1,1];
f(a)
 disp('all true +++++++++++++');
a=[1];
f(a)
a=[0,1;1,1];
f(a)
a=[0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0];
f(a)
a=[0,0,1;0,1,1;1,1,1];
f(a)
a=[1,1,1,0,0;1,1,1,1,0;0,1,1,0,0;0,1,0,0,0];
f(a)
a=[0,1,1,0,0,0;0,1,1,0,0,0;1,1,1,1,0,0;1,1,1,1,1,1;0,0,1,0,0,0];
f(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>129</s> 127 bytes

```
3>GraphDiameter@Graph[#,#<->#2&@@@Select[#~Tuples~2,!FreeQ[#-#2&@@#,0]&]]&@Position[#,1]&&{#,Thread@#}~FreeQ~{___,1,0..,1,___}&
```

#### Explanation:

First, if there is a `0` between two `1`s on the same row or column, the array is not L-convex, because we can't connect the two `1`s.

After excluding this case, every two `1`s on the same row or column can be connected by a straight path. We can generate a graph, whose vertices are the positions of `1`s in the array, and edges are pairs of `1`s on the same row or column. Then the array is L-convex if and only if the [diameter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphDiameter.html) of the graph is less than 3.

Comment: Can you give an explanation how this works? I am not gonna upvote gibberish nobody could possibly understand=)

Comment: How does this recognize the first and fourth false instances (the disconnected ones)?

Comment: @Zgarb If the graph is disconnected, its diameter is infinity.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 290 bytes

Ok, maybe it won't win any awards for brevity, but it does use a novel approach. See the ungolfed version for how it works.

Proof for this method can be found in: [Cellular Automata and Discrete Complex Systems](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nynMCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=l-convex+NW+NE&source=bl&ots=eubAlTlqsQ&sig=DiXpUjfTzo1Il-iVFXU8rZ7C__0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI7YOYiYm0yAIViroaCh0MbwEN#v=onepage&q=l-convex%20NW%20NE&f=false).

```js
L=a=>[1,0,1].every($=>(a=a[0].map((_,col)=>a.map(row=>row[col]))).map(r=>($?r.reverse():r).join``).every((r,i,b)=>r.replace(/^(0*)(1*)(0*)$|(.+)/,(_,s,m,o,e)=>(c=e)?'':!m||b[i-1]&&+b[i-1][s.length]?1:b.every((r,j)=>j<i||(c=c||!+r[l=s.length])?r.search(`0{${l}}.*0{${o.length}}`)+1:1)||'')))
```

Ungolfed:

```js
function L(a) {
  /* Runs three times and ensure all pass validation
   * 1: horizontally reversed
   * 2: 90 degrees rotated
   * 3: original
   *
   *     | 1:  | 2:  | 3:
   * =====================
   * 001 | 100 | 111 | 001
   * 011 | 110 | 011 | 011
   * 111 | 111 | 001 | 111
   *
   * By finding maximal rectangles with corners on all NW and NE corners
   * (separately) of a HV-convex polyomino and ensuring it doesn't enter the
   * boundaries labelled ABCD for the rectangle X below:
   *
   *   A  |         |  B
   * -----===========-----
   *      |    X    |
   * -----===========-----
   *   C  |         |  D
   *
   * The first iteration tests the NE corners and horizontal convexity.
   * The second iteration test vertical convexity.
   * The third iteration tests the NW corners.
   *
   * If all pass then the polyomino is L-convex.
   */
  return [1,0,1].every(function($){
    return (a=a[0].map((_,col)=>{
      // Transpose rows with columns
      return a.map(row=>row[col])
    })).map(row=>{
      // Join rows as strings and on odd iterations reverse them
      return ($ ? row.reverse() : row).join``
    }).every(function(row, i, b) {
      if (i == 0) console.log(b.join('\n'));
      return row.replace(/^(0*)(1*)(0*)$|(.+)/, function(_, start, middle, end, invalid) {
        // Non H-convex polyomino (0 between 1s)
        if (invalid) return '';
        // Is not a NW corner (character above is 1)
        if (!middle || b[i-1] && +b[i-1][start.length]) return 1;
        c=1;
        return b.every(function(row, j) {
          // Above or below maximal rectangle from corner
          if (j < i || !(c=c&&+row[l=start.length])) {
            // Area before and after maximal rectangle doesn't contain 1
            return row.search(`0{${l}}.*0{${end.length}}`)+1
          }
          return 1;
        }) || '';
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Ha, that article is where I got the inspiration for this challenge!

Comment: @Zgarb The article was great and one of the few I could find that made sense to someone who isn't mathematically orientated.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 174

Looking at the grid of empty or filled cells, for any pair of filled cells I check the horizontal paths to the other cell column (there can be 1 if the cells are on the same row, else or 2) and the vertical paths to the other cell row (there can be 1 or 2 too). If I find an empty cell in both vertical paths or both horizontal paths, then there can not be an L shaped path between the cells.

(I had a hard time trying to put up this explanation - I hope to have been clear)

Test running the snippet below in any EcmaScript 6 compliant browser

```js
F=p=>!p.some((n,y)=>n.some((q,x)=>q&&p.some((o,u)=>o.some((q,t)=>{for(f=0,i=y;q&i<=u;i++)f|=!p[i][x]|2*!p[i][t];if(f<3)for(f=0,j=x;q&j<=t;j++)f|=!n[j]|2*!o[j];return f>2}))))

// TEST
console.log=(...x)=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

tko = [
 [[0,1],[1,0]]
,[[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
,[[1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0]]
,[[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1]]
,[[0,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0]]
,[[0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1]]
]
tko.forEach(t=>(console.log(t.join`\n`+`\nFalse? ${F(t)}\n`)));
tok = [
 [[1]]
,[[0,1],[1,1]]
,[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]
,[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1]]
,[[1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]
,[[0,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0,0]]
]  
tok.forEach(t=>(console.log(t.join`\n`+`\nTrue? ${F(t)}\n`)));

// LESS GOLFED

U=p=>
  !p.some((n,y)=>  
    n.some((q,x)=> 
      q && p.some((o,u)=>  
        o.some((q,t)=>{
          for(f=0,i=y; q&i<=u; i++)f|=!p[i][x]|2*!p[i][t]
          if (f<3)
            for(f=0,j=x; q&j<=t; j++)f|=!n[j]|2*!o[j]
          return f>2
        })
      )
    )
  )
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```