# Is this string a square?

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, decision-problem

A string is considered to be square if the following conditions are met:

- Each line has the same number of characters
- The number of characters on each line is equal to the number of lines.

Your task is to write a program or function which determines whether or not a given input string is a square.

You may require input to be delimited by your choice of LF, CR, or CRLF.

The newline character(s) are not considered part of the line's length.

You may require there to be or to not be a trailing newline in input, which doesn't count as an additional line.

Input is a string or 1D char array; it is not a list of strings.

You may assume input is non-empty and only contains printable ASCII, including spaces.

You must output a truthy value for square strings and a falsy one for other strings.

### Truthy test cases:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

```
.
```

```
.s.
.ss
.s.
(s represents space)
```

```
ss
ss
(s represents space)
```

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
```

### Falsy test cases:

```
..
.
```

```
.
```

```
.
```

```
....


....
```

```
4444
333
22
```

```
333
333
```

```
abc.def.ghi
```

Note extra blank lines in some of the falsy cases.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Language Design: 2-D Pattern Matching](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/language-design-2-d-pattern-matching). Problem #5 is the same as this question.

Comment: @mbomb007 I feel like the different winning criteria make this not a duplicate? "Golfiness" was one of the voting criteria but I don't think answers to that question will largely reflect on the ones here.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm voting to leave this question open because, while it is a subset of the other question, the other question is restricted to languages created specifically for that question.

Comment: @mbomb007: That's not a duplicate, because that question asks you to design a language for the purpose of answering the question, rather than answering in an existing language. Very few of the answers here would be legal there.

Comment: The solutions there are legal here, however. Many of the answers have an exact solution to this challenge contained in them.

Comment: @mbomb007: That's no reason to close *this* challenge, and give people nowhere to post their answers in pre-existing languages, though. It might potentially be an argument for closing the other challenge (because it's just a more restrictive version of this one), although I'd consider it a poor argument and believe both should be left open.

Comment: Technically, the first requirement is redundant as it can never be false if the second is true.

Comment: Suggested test case: `foo` `bar` `bazz` (those three lines in that order) - my PCRE2 regex could be [4 bytes shorter](https://regex101.com/r/xkQe8f/15) and still match all the test cases, but would give false positives on shapes that are otherwise square but have a longer last line.

Comment: can i input as an array of strings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 3 bytes

```
ṇẹṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@HO9oe7dj7c2fj/v1Jafj5XUmIREFcpAQA)

Full program. Outputs `true.` for truthy, `false.` for falsey.

### Explanation

```
ṇẹṁ
ṇ     Split {standard input} into lines
 ẹ    Split {each line} into basic elements {in this case, characters}
  ṁ   Assert that the result is square
```

I was a bit sceptical about the usefulness of the `ṁ` builtin when it was added, but I can't really deny that it's helpful here…

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 7 bytes

```
ṇẹ.\l~l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@HO9oe7durF5NTl/P@vlJafz5WUWATEVUoA)

Non-builtin solution. <s>*Still* beats all the other entries, as of the time of writing.</s> EDIT: Not quite, the equal-length Jelly entry got in while I was writing this, and beats it via the timestamp tiebreak.

### Explanation

```
ṇẹ.\l~l
ṇ         Split {standard input} into lines
 ẹ        Split {each line} into basic elements {in this case, characters}
   \l     Assert that the result is rectangular, and the number of columns
  .  ~l     is equal to the number of rows
```

Comment: Correct tool for the job!

Comment: `ṁ` = "Assert that the result is square" :(

Comment: There was a challenge a while back where I was struggling to write an assert-square (it'd have been something like `.\l~l` at the time, except that the backslash command, which among other things asserts that its input is a *rectangle*, was broken; note that even if we replace `ṁ` with `.\l~l`, this is *still* the shortest program here; come to think of it, I'll add that to the post). The backslash command got fixed, but the language author decided to add an assert-square at the same time. I was thinking "surely that's never going to come up again". Apparently I was wrong.

Comment: What does the `(2)` signify?

Comment: @Phoenix: Version number of the language, this won't work in Brachylog v1. Most people just say "Brachylog" (just like most people say "Perl" rather than "Perl 5"), but I got into the habit a while back because I do use Brachylog v1 on rare occasions.

Comment: The 3 byte solution without the dots under and over the characters (`nem`) means `no` in Hungarian :D

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer why is that problematic? Or do you just think it's a little boring?

Comment: @iFreilicht It's bad because it outgolfs every other golfing language so far.

Answer (score 23):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
x=input().split('\n')
print{len(x)}==set(map(len,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERDU6@4ICezREM9Jk9dk6ugKDOvpDonNU@jQrPW1rY4tUQjN7FAAyigU6Gp@f@/eiIIxOThptQB) or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##dUxBCsMgELz7Cm8qBKHaUyE/2UtKlQjpRtRQ29K329WeO7Azs8vMxmdZdzSt3ZznXmZ1YbzOWee4hSIFoFCMJ1eOhO/NoazqM8/ZFXlfoqTDVJVqjzVsjp9GNWA8iqRSTAELr1P/MXkqDteE33fA65I6vQQTmmbpAPwvPacBe5aE@OfPBEBrLaAxtA9HJL4)

Comment: I love the fact that this is both golfed and readable.

Comment: You do not need the `'\n'`, just leave it empty (since there are no spaces and tabs in the input).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 no, it does not work for square strings that contain spaces!!!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Must it work with spaces? As i understood there are never spaces in the input.

Comment: You misunderstood the specs: *You may assume input is non-empty and only contains printable ASCII.*, and whitespace (` `) is printable ASCII

Comment: Why not just make a lambda like this?https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fYRvzPycxNyklUSHHqjonNU8jR7PW1rY4tUQjN7FAAyigk6Op@b@gKDOvRKNCI1opUUFJR0lBQSkWKAoA

Comment: @irapsaged OP didn't allowed `Input is a string or 1D char array; it is not a list of strings.`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @irapsaged np c:

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
s=>!(s=s.split`
`).some(x=>x.length-s.length)
```

- 1 byte saved thank to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

---

### Explanation

1. Split the string to an array on newlines.
2. Loop over the array.
3. Subtract the length of the array from the length of each line.
4. If a non-zero (i.e., truthy) value is returned for any line, the string is not square.
5. Negate the result of the loop to get `true` for square and `false` for not.

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>!(s=s.split`
`).some(x=>x.length-s.length)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value=`foo
bar
baz`)
```

```html
<textarea id=i></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I think you can save a byte with ``s=>!(s=s.split`\n`).some(x=>x.length-s.length)``

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions. I've a terrible habit of dismissing `!some` out of hand, simply because it's the same length as `every`.

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
Ỵ¬⁼Z$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i2H1jxq3BOl8v///0QQ4EoCAa5kEOBKAQGuVBAAAA)

Thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for -2

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
¶¡€gDgQP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LZDCx81rUl3SQ8M@P9fSUkpMTGRK7EYiBMTgTwA)

***-2 thanks to Riley, this is basically his answer ._.***

```
Code       # Explanation                  | Truthy Example          | Falsy Example
-----------#------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------
¶¡         # Split on newlines            | [['aaa','aaa','aaa']]   | [['aa']]
  €g       # Get length of each           | [[3,3,3]]               | [[2]]
    D      # Dupe                         | [[3,3,3],[3,3,3]]       | [[2],[2]]
     g     # Get length                   | [[3,3,3],3]             | [[2],1]
      Q    # Check equality               | [[1,1,1]]               | [[0]]
       P   # Take product                 | 1                       | 0
```

Comment: @Riley ahhh, nice catch, my original idea was more along the lines of what you had but slightly different. Iterated two more times and didn't catch my math error.

Comment: I don't think "Header" is a valid form on input.

Comment: @Phoenix is **that** better?

Comment: Probably, IDK 05ab1e

Comment: Input can also be taken in with three quotes, [like this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0LZDC13Six81rUkPDPj/X0lJKTExkSuxGIgTE4E8AA).

Comment: If you get the length of each first you can avoid the `s`. Like this [`¶¡€gDgQP`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9zaPf/Q9sOLXzUtCbdJT0w4P//xMRErsRiIE5MBAA)

Comment: @Riley already got down to 8-bytes by changing the strategy entirely.

Comment: @carusocomputing I thought of that too, but [it doesn't quite work](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9zaPf/Q9sOLXzUtCbYRc8p8P//xMRErsRiIAbShkbG2DAA)

Comment: @Riley do you want the answer? This was basically all you after a certain point lmao. I feel bad still getting points for it.

Comment: @carusocomputing Nah, it's not that far from your original solution. I had enough fun working on it, I don't need the rep or anything.

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
=Ur.Q)¥Uy
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=PVVyLlEppVV5&input=ImFiYwpkZWYKZ2hpIg==)

#### Explanation

```
 =Ur.Q)¥ Uy
U=Ur.Q)==Uy
             // Implicit: U = input string, Q = quotation mark
U=    )      // Set U to
  Ur.Q       //   U with each non-newline (/./g) replaced with a quotation mark.
       ==Uy  // Return U == U transposed. U is padded to a rectangle with spaces before
             // transposing; if U was not a rectangle before, or the sides are not of
             // equal length, the result will not be the same as U.
             // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

---

Using some features implemented shortly after this challenge was posted, this can be 6 bytes:

```
r.Q
¥y
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ci5RCqV5&input=ImFiYwpkZWYKZ2hpIg==)

#### Explanation

```
       // Implicit: U = input string
r.Q    // Replace each non-newline (/./g) in U with a quotation mark.
       // Newline: set U to the result.
¥      // Return U ==
 y     //   U transposed.
       // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: How in the world are you *so* fast?

Comment: @totallyhuman I happened to see the question the instant it was posted, and it took me two minutes to come up with an algorithm. After that it was just implementing and posting. (Also I have things to get back to haha)

Comment: Nice :) I knew `y` was the solution but mine was coming in at a few more bytes.

Comment: "*Using some features implemented shortly after this challenge was posted*" - You can now post that as your asnwer.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ỴµL;L€E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i2HtvpY@zxqWuP6////RCDgSgICrmQg4EoBAgA)

### Explanation

```
Ỵµ       Split the input on newline and use as input in the second link     
  L      Get the number of list items
   ;     And append to that
    L€   A list with the legth of each list item
      E  Check to see if all items are equal.
```

Comment: Your TIO link seems to indicate that no trailing newline should be there.

Comment: @Phoenix fixed / reverted...

Comment: This just checks to see if all lines are the same length - it actually doesn't take the newline count into account at all. When you reach the E atom, you have a list of line lengths and that's all.

Comment: @Christian fixed and shortened. Sorry 'bout the confusion, I guess something went wrong after I had a working solution and I tried to golf that..

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, <s>38</s> 34 bytes

```hs
l=length
(all=<<(.l).(==).l).lines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcXBCoAgDADQe18xpINCCdXV/YmXFZrSGpH@/6J3eYXalZhVGTnJ2cuQ0RIzhmA9O28R3T9XSU1vqgIIz1ulwwgZDO1HlGXdokx@NvoB)

Pointfree version of `f s = all ((==length (lines s)).length) (lines s)`, i.e split the input into lines and check if the length of each line is equal to the number of lines.

Edit: Thanks to @xnor for 4 bytes.

Comment: I think you can use `all` for `map` to cut the `and.`.

Answer (score 9):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
S≡T'a¶
```

Takes a string and prints either `1` or `0`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfF/8KPOhSHqiYe2/f//P1rJ0Mg4Ji8xKTkmr6KySklHSQ@IFRRi8hQUgIxEIADKwkmQvB6YiMmD0CAWCIJYSrEA)
The first line iterates over the test cases; remove it if you want to test on a single value.

### Explanation

Husk is a new functional golfing language created by myself and [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62393/leo).
It's missing a lot of features and development is ongoing.
Its main feature is a rigid type system that allows us to overload higher order functions.

On a high level, the program works like this:

```
S≡T'a¶  Define a function:
     ¶  split on newlines,
  T'a   transpose and pad to rectangle using character 'a',
 ≡      check if this has the same shape as
S       the split input.
```

The function `≡` actually checks if two arrays have the same shape and the same distribution of truthy elements.
In Husk, all characters except the null byte are truthy, and that won't occur in our inputs.
Also, `S` is the **S-combinator**, a function that takes as inputs two functions, here `≡` and `T'a`, and returns a new function that maps `x` to `≡(x)(T'a x)`.
The result of `S` is composed with `¶`, and that function is applied to the input implicitly.

How does Husk know that it should apply `S` to the next function, but `¶` should be composed with the function on its left?
Simple: it just tries every interpretation and picks the one where the types make sense.
This is explained in more detail in the [Husk documentation](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki).

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
.
.
^(.(.)*)(?<-2>¶\1)*$(?(2).)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fj0uPK05DT0NPU0tTw95G18ju0LYYQ00tFQ17DSNNPc3//wE) Explanation: The first stage simply changes all printable ASCII into the same character to make it easier to match. (It could be done without, but this is code golf, not code challenge.) The second stage then matches at least one character on the first line. However, for each additional character on the first line, it then optionally matches a newline followed by a copy of the first line. The final part of the expression causes the match to fail if there are more columns than rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, this outputs true for this [testcase](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JKEgQY8rTkNPQ09TS1PD3kbXyO7QthhDTS0VDXsNI009zf//9bgA).

Comment: @KritixiLithos I believe the submission requires a trailing newline in input, which is allowed.

Comment: Also I believe using `\S\n;` instead of the first line saves one byte

Comment: @KritixiLithos Actually replacing `.` with `.` saves two, but thanks.

Comment: @Neil That's really clever!

Answer (score 6):

## Pure bash (no utilities), 55

```bash
mapfile -t a
for l in ${a[@]};{
((c+=${#l}^${#a[@]}))
}
```

- `mapfile` reads the input into array `a`
- then the number of elements of the array is XORed with each line length, and the sum taken.  For a perfect square, each XOR result (and thus the sum) will be 0.  For anything else, the result will be >0.

The opposite sense of this is returned as a shell return code (examine with `echo $?`) - perfect square is 1, anything else is 0.

[Try it online (truthy)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexIC0zJ1VBt0QhkSstv0ghRyEzT0GlOjHaIbbWuppLQyNZ21alWjmnNg5IgkU1Nblq/6cmZ@QrqNj/TwQBLhwkAA).

[Try it online (falsy)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexIC0zJ1VBt0QhkSstv0ghRyEzT0GlOjHaIbbWuppLQyNZ21alWjmnNg5IgkU1Nblq/6cmZ@QrqNj/NwECLmNjYy4jIwA).

---

#### Previous answer using eval-escape-expansion hell, 78:

```bash
mapfile -t a
echo $[0$(eval eval echo +\\$\{#a[{0..$[${#a[@]}-1]}]}^${#a[@]})]
```

[Try it online (truthy)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexIC0zJ1VBt0QhkSs1OSNfQSXaQEUjtSwxRwFCgMS0Y2JUYqqVE6OrDfT0VKJVQEyH2Fpdw9ja2No4GFcz9v//RBDgwkECAA).

[Try it online (falsy)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzexIC0zJ1VBt0QhkSs1OSNfQSXaQEUjtSwxRwFCgMS0Y2JUYqqVE6OrDfT0VKJVQEyH2Fpdw9ja2No4GFcz9v9/EyDgMjY25jIyAgA).

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 27 bytes

```
{.lines==all .lines».comb}
```

Tests whether the number of lines in the input string is equal to the number of characters on each line.

Comment: does this ignore the new-line character?

Comment: Yes, newlines are not returned by the `.lines` method.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Ỵ¬zƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i2H1lQdm/j//3@lxKSYvGQlAA)

Input via command-line argument. The input must be given with no trailing newline (otherwise the program sees a blank line at the end, which isn't the same length as the others); this I/O format is explicitly allowed by the question.

So far, the shortest answer that doesn't use an "is a square" builtin. (There's an existing 5-byte Jelly answer that works on similar principles, but is wrong, incorrectly considering `"aa\na"` to be square – this answer is not only shorter, it also fixes that issue.)

### Explanation

```
Ỵ¬zƑ
Ỵ      split {the input} on newlines
 ¬     replace every truthy character (i.e. all of them) with 0
   Ƒ   does that remain unchanged, after
  z      a ragged transpose that pads to a rectangle using {the input}?
```

There are two main cases:

- The string is not even a rectangle. In this case, the "transpose and pad to rectangle" builtin `z` will pad the string to a rectangle, but uses copies of the user input as the padding, which are not zeroes (even if the input uses the character `'0'`, this compares unequal to the integer `0`). So there's no way the ragged transpose can leave the split-and-zeroed version of the input unchanged.
- The string is a rectangle. In this case, the ragged transpose won't apply any padding, but will produce a rectangle of zeroes with the number of rows and columns swapped from the transpose input. The only way the input and output can match is therefore if the number of rows equals the number of columns, i.e. the input is a square. (If the input *is* a square, the transpose will leave it unchanged because, as every element is a zero, all the elements will be the same and thus it doesn't matter that the transpose swaps some of them.)

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, 7 bytes

```
CImL1.z
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=CImL1.z&input=aaaaa%0Abbbbb%0Accccc%0Addddd%0Aeeeee&debug=0)

Requires no trailing newline. Replaces the input with a 2D array of 1s where a 1 represents any character in the original input. Then we check whether that array is unchanged after transposing it (replacing columns with rows). Only a square will return true in such a situation.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <del>96</del> <del>91</del> <del>90</del> 87 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*
*-1 byte thanks to @TheLethalCoder*
*-2 bytes thanks to @OlivierGrégoire*

```java
a->java.util.Arrays.stream(a.split("\n")).allMatch(x->x.length()==a.split("\n").length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZGxTsMwEIbn5CmsTo5ErlLLRGklGLp1KhthuLpO4uKeI9upGlAfmznYoRJigHbgt3R3On@@@yXv8IC5aSTttq990260EkxodI6tUBF7T1nQue88@pAORm3ZPtzytbeKqucXhrZyWYCTXRgHrVcaypaEV4ZgeS7uv@gb9miMlkgLVrI56zFffD96sBY7B85biXuO4BqtPB8VNMoyQK1X6EXNj/niCFpS5Wuezec/sHM/65PZYD1qPGZPtvV1xwQ66e7SZN05L/dgWg9NMOU18RKwaXTHR6UxBW3QxvAW9s7@xuEyglEF/Z6GEWkSfC5Ru@tsAhR0xe7/gwDiynhidZm/DSpoOp0WNJlcxgcwhIGMv3ZKT/0HmVygqOUn)

Comment: @Phoenix Fixed, thank you! :-)

Comment: You can remove the space at `String[]s` and you can remove the `,0` in the `.split("\\n");` for -3 bytes. And the semicolon/`;` at the very end you won't have to count, so that another -1. Oh, and you have to include the `java.util.` in front of the `Arrays` I'm afraid. Imports/usings are part of the byte-count as well.

Comment: Since you forgot to include the `java.util.`, just a regular for-loop like this `for(String x:s)if(x.length()!=s.length)return 0>1;return 1>0;` seems to be shorter than `return java.util.Arrays.stream(s).anyMatch(l->l.length()!=s.length);`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for saving me several bytes! :-)

Comment: Is it not just `\n`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) takes a `String` (a regex) and, optionally, an `int` (a delimiter) as parameters. Therefore, I thought the backslash had to be escaped. But at the end of the day it worked without escaping, so thanks for saving me 1 byte! :-)

Comment: Repeating the `a.split("\n")` is actually shorter! `a->java.util.Arrays.stream(a.split("\n")).allMatch(x->x.length()==a.split("\n").length)`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire In fact it is 1 char shorter, but for some reason TIO says it is [91 chars, 99 bytes] long (compared to the [90 chars, 90 bytes] of my current answer).

Comment: Well, it's totally explainable: Stackoverflow add some blank empty unicode characters to cut the long  code blocks. This way, the comments aren't taking too much space. It happens quite a lot on this website because of its nature. By the way, I counted 87 chars, not 89 (or 91), and I just double-checked again: 87 chars, not any single more. If you count manually or retype it exactly as is, you'll see that. In this case, the extra characters are between the last `.` and the last `length`.

Comment: Hmmm... some more are present as well between `leng` and `th()`. So apparently, they appear first after the 60th char then every 20 characters.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I suspected that from the beginning. It makes sense. I re-typed everything on my IDE, pasted on TIO and _voilà_: 87 bytes! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
10H&XXot&n=h
```

The input string is defined using string concatenation (`[...]`) and with the code point `10` to represent LF. For example, `['aaa' 10 'bb']` is interpreted in MATL as string `'aaa'` concatenated with the character with code point `10` concatenated with string `'bb'`.

The output is a non-empty numeric vector, which is [truthy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/36398) if and only if all its entries are non-zero.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/QwEMtIiK/RC3PNuO/S8j/aPW0/Hx1BUMDBfWkxCIYo0o9lktdT50rWj0RBCDCRDJjgbr0IAJ6eggekAEWgogAAVgJRBVUnQkQQDQaGxtDGEZGYBk4H8SIBQA)**

#### Explanation

Consider input `['4444' 10 '333' 10 '22']`.

```
10H   % Push 10 (code point of LF). Push 2
      % STACK: 10, 2
&XX   % Regexp with three arguments. First argument is implicit input (string);
      % second is 2, which indicates that we want to split the input; third is
      % 10, which is the character to split on. The result is a cell array of
      % matched strings
      % STACK: {'4444', '333', '22'}
o     % Concatenate into a numeric 2D array of code points, right-padding with
      % zeros if needed
      % STACK: [52 52 52 52; 51 51 51 0; 50 50 0 0]
t&n   % Duplicate. Push number of rows and number of columns
      % STACK: [52 52 52 52; 51 51 51 0; 50 50 0 0], 3, 4
=     % Are they equal?
      % STACK: [52 52 52 52; 51 51 51 0; 50 50 0 0], 0
h     % Concatenate into a row vector (in column-major order). Implicit display
      % STACK: [52 51 50 52 51 50 52 51 0 52 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
|€gDgQP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5lHTmnSX9MCA//8TQYALBwkA)

Comment: Kind of cheating imo, that's basically taking `n` inputs instead of 1 and why my original answer didn't work.

Comment: @carusocomputing No, `|` means "take the rest of the input and split by newlines" which is in no way taking multiple inputs. You just have to treat STDIN as a single input.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
function(s)all(nchar(n<-strsplit(s,'
')[[1]])==length(n))
```

An anonymous function; Splits on newlines, computes the length of each line, and checks if all are the same as the number of lines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhBCoAgEEX3c5GZgQra50nExRRZgYyhtunyZvh5nwcvVW@qf3QrV1TKLCGQbqck0mXMJeU7XIXygIBs7ewcGxN2PcpJylw94YQMTT5GWCW1vz1MbQDwqwcRgR/k@gE)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

```
s=$<.read.split $/,-1;p [s.size]==s.map(&:size)|[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9hWxUavKDUxRa@4ICezRENFX0fXUNO6QCG6WK84syo11ta2WC83sUBDzQrE1ayJjv3/Py0/nyspsQqIiwA)

### Explanation

1. Split input into array on newline.
2. Assert that an array containing only the size of this array is equal to an array containing all uniq (set union with empty array) sizes of all elements in this array.

Comment: Save a character with  `.split($/,-1);` -> `.split $/,-1;`

Comment: Save more by using `lines` instead of `read` and then `split` (but then you have to add 1 to `size` because the lines include the trailing newline)

Comment: 45 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulivuCAns0RDRV9TLzEnx766pqKmQq84syrV1rZYLzm/NA8sV1v7v0AhTU9DKS0/nyspsQqIi7iUNLm4YKJIgv8B "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## R, 35 bytes

```
all(nchar(x<-scan(,""))==length(x))
```

Takes input from stdin. Checks that the number of characters in each line is equal to the total number of lines. Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` as appropriate.

Comment: note that inputs need to be wrapped in quotes or this might break on spaces within each line.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

```
s=>(a=s.split`
`,a.every(l=>l.length==a.length))
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
qN/:,_,f=:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9BP30onXifN1krr//9EIOACE0lAwJUMBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
!fnl.zlT.z
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman.

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=!fnl.zlT.z&input=aaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
!fnl.zlT.z
 f     T.z     Filter lines of the input
  nl.zl        whose length is not the number of lines
!              and return whether there are no such lines.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/), 56 bytes

```ml
let f t=List.(for_all(fun l->String.length l=length t)t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89DsIwDIVnegrLUzKQC1ThAiAxMFZVFYFTIpkUJeb8oUoLAz@DZT@97z3J09nduBQmAQ9iDyGLUX5Kg2NW/hGBt7uTpBBHwxRHuQLb9RAtugaVBttsXM6UZuGhQ2OwBTTYgwXvOJNuP4EFeU3V/2nsvwuW2C9ntd6rIvf5BxkoXjhEAjzusSlP)

Answer (score 2):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 43 bytes

```
{_?~_lA||h=h+1┘g=g+_lA|~g%_lA||_Xp]\_xg/h=h
```

Me, I'm happy with how short a QBasic derivative got to go on this challenge.

### Explanation:

```
{_?       DO infinitely: ask the user for input, store as A$
~    |    IF
 _lA|       The length of A$   (implicitly <> 0)
h=h+1     Add 1 to our line counter
┘         (syntactic linebreak)
g=g+_lA|  Add the length of this line to the running total of line lengths
~      |  IF
 g%_lA|     The length of the running total modulo the length of the last string
            yields anything but 0, there is a discrepancy between earlier line
            lengths and this one.
_Xp]      THEN QUIT, printing 0, end IF
\         ELSE (refers to the LEN(A$), user didn't input anything.
_xg/h=h   QUIT (the inf. loop) printing -1 if the root of the chars is the row count
            or 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
qCC.z.z
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qCC.z.z&input=foo%0Abar%0Abaz&debug=0)

Transpose the input with truncation twice, then check if the result is the same as the original.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

29 bytes of code + `-p0` flags.

```perl
/.*/;$_=/^(.{@{+}}
){@{+}}\z/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAsM/uvraelbq8Tb6sdp6FU7VGvX1nJpQuiYKv3//9Py87mSEouAuIoLAA)

**Explanations:**
`/.*/` matches the first line, and thus makes `@+` contain the length of the first line. Then the regex checks whether the string contains `@+` lines of length `@+`.

Answer (score 2):

## MacOS Bash, 34

```bash
rs -EH|awk '{print $1}'|uniq|wc -l
```

`rs` is part of the default MacOS image.  This will also work on Linux if `rs` is installed; it is on TIO.

- `rs -EH` lists the length of each line, along with the number of lines
- `awk` strips out extraneous info
- `uniq` outputs one line if the line lengths and number of lines are all the same, but more otherwise
- `wc -l` outputs `1` if the input is square or a greater number otherwise.

Try it online: [Truthy](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6hYQdfVoyaxPFtBvbqgKDOvREHFsFa9pjQvs7CmPFlBN@f//0QQ4MJBAgA), [Falsey](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6hYQdfVoyaxPFtBvbqgKDOvREHFsFa9pjQvs7CmPFlBN@f/fxMg4DI2NuYyMgIA).

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 49 bytes

```
{s=length($0)}L{x+=L!=s}{L=s}END{print x?0:L==NR}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/utg2JzUvvSRDQ8VAs9anukLb1kfRtri22gdIuPq5VBcUZeaVKFTYG1j52Nr6BdX@/6@np8cFxQA)

Could also have used a `BEGIN` block to set `FS=""` but that would be the same byte-count. For some reason using the `-F""` argument never seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éΘ┌«■/ÉW(
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82e9daaefe2f905728&i=foo%0Abar%0Abaz%0A%0A.%0A%0A.+.%0A.++%0A.+.%0A%0A++%0A++%0A%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0Aaaaaa%0A%0A..%0A.%0A.%0A%0A4444%0A333%0A22%0A%0A333%0A333%0A%0Aabc.def.ghi&a=1&m=1)

Turns out that due to way pairwise difference is calculated, I don't need to worry about the equivalence of `k` and `x-k` here. Saving 5 bytes.

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
Lc{%mc%+:u
L             Collect rows in a list
 c{%m         List of length of each row
     c%+      Append number of rows to the list
        :u    All elements in the list are equal
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 48 bytes

```powershell
($a=$args-split'
'|%{$_.Length}).Count-eq($a|gu)
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

($a=$args-split'
'|%{$_.Length}).Count-eq($a|gu)

}

@(

,($true,@"
foo
bar
baz
"@)

,($true,@"
.
"@)

,($true,@"
. .
.  
. .
"@)

,($true,@"


"@)

,($true,@"
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
"@)

,($false,@"
..
.
"@)

,($false,@"
.

"@)

,($false,@"

.
"@)

,($false,@"
....


....
"@)

,($false,@"
4444
333
22
"@)

,($false,@"
333
333
"@)

,($false,@"
abc.def.ghi
"@)

) | % {
    $expected,$s = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: True
True: True
True: True
True: True
True: True
True: False
True: False
True: False
True: False
True: False
True: False
True: False
```

Explanation:

- ``` $args-split"``n"|%{$_.Length} ``` creates an array of length of each line.
- `$a.Count` counts elements of the array
- `$a|gu` apply Get-Unique to the array. The result is one integer element if all lines has same length.
- `$a.Count-eq($a|gu)` compares `Count` of element with result of the Get-Unique. It's `true` if all lines has same length and this length equals to `Count`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
Y0MMa^ny=Zy
```

Takes a multiline string (with no trailing newline) as a command-line argument. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZME1NYV5ueT1aeSIsIiIsIiIsIlwiYWJjXG5kZWZcbiAgIFwiIl0=)

#### Explanation

```
Y0MMa^ny=Zy
    a        Command-line argument
     ^n      Split on newlines
  MM         To each character of each line, map:
 0           0
             This results in a nested list of 0's, one for each character
Y            Yank it into the y variable
       y=    That nested list equals
         Zy  Its transpose
```

For example, with inputs `"abc\ndefg"` and `"ab\ncd"`:

```
    a^n      ["abc";"defg"]       ["ab";"cd"]
Y0MM         [[0;0;0];[0;0;0;0]]  [[0;0];[0;0]]
         Zy  [[0;0];[0;0];[0;0]]  [[0;0];[0;0]]
       y=    0                    1
```

Comment: This gives a false negative when spaces are in certain places, including a square made entirely of spaces (test case #4) and any square with spaces only in its last line.

Comment: @Deadcode Input containing spaces needs to be wrapped in quotes. I updated the DSO link to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
¶o²⁋=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCtm/CsuKBiz0iLCIiLCJcImZvb1xcbmJhclxcbmJhelwiIl0=)

```
¶o²⁋=
¶o    # Remove all newlines
  ²   # Format as a square
   ⁋  # Join by newlines
    = # Equal to the input?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (.NET), 55 bytes

```
^.((.))*(?<-1>
.(?=(?<-2>.)*(?(2).)
)(?<2>.)*)*$(?(1).)
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xkQe8f/7)

Neil said in his [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124921/17216), "It could be done without, but this is code golf, not code challenge." Well, here's a pure regex answer that *needs* to do it that way (without substitutions done beforehand to lighten the load).

The last line must end with exactly one newline. To remove this restriction would result in worse golf.

In this explanation, `¶` indicates a raw newline in the regex:

```
^                    # Anchor to start of string
.                    # Skip one character, due to the fact that when we count
                     # the number of rows, matching it up with our capture count,
                     # the first row won't becounted.
((.))*               # Add the remaining length of this line to the capture count
                     # of both \1 and \2.
(?<-1>               # If there is at least one capture on the \1 stack, do the
                     # following:
    ¶                # Advance to the next line (thus proving that the entire
                     # previous line was processed)
    .                # Advance by one character (because we already did the same
                     # on the first line)
    (?=              # Lookahead - allows the same part of the string to be
                     # matched in multiple ways.
        (?<-2>.)*    # For each capture remaining on the \2 stack, advance one
                     # character. Will stop short if it reaches the end of the
                     # line before the \2 stack is emptied.
        (?(2).)¶     # Assert that if the \2 stack is not empty, there is at
                     # least one more character remaining in this line, but also
                     # assert that this is the end of the line - effectively
                     # asserting that the \2 stack is empty and we're at the end
                     # of the line.
    )
    (?<2>.)*         # Having already proved that this line is of equal length to
                     # the previous, transfer its length back into the capture
                     # count of group \2.
)*                   # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum zero.
$                    # Assert that we've reached the end of the string, or a
                     # newline after which it is the end of the string.
(?(1).)              # Effectively assert that the \1 stack is empty, as it is
                     # impossible to match one more non-newline character after
                     # reaching the end of the string.
```

## Regex (Perl / PCRE2), <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```
^(?=((?|
()|.(?=.*
(\2?+.)))+)+
\2$)((?=^|.+(\4?+
.+)).)+\4$|^.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJLb@IwEL77V8wGi3o2yC6PvRBChNTucU89RlgBnBIpJChOVZWY/nU6Dki73UodyTPfvL4ZWz6apvx1ObwBbyLoynqblcBVRG68eFg9rZZnlteN4Kf4PlosI7Jj7ICfhsNjU1RtkFYBFdt/XW6pFrb7@nCMGECRg@AahkOwLxvbEpce3Y/GWJm7wR12VAFg1Tp1yo8tIQauZU/Up173RWnEYonQXSkp7VyZ2Tb61Cb/9p37xn4hEEJ4zndQvFGYBE/Ni5lDMA9@Z6U18wAl7RPzckRcCpzyViQ/0hUquIpTh2eKphVXPstVH@Aa0V88Hvs1z2CIDbrrTK5phbPWj38etL4QXSxE4phAJwnLn0ykkySUiBhiyNIJR8rHaydDkc6SkMkQUWKYzrhbS365DIC2bvdv0BrbwjazxjLm8rpmbpM1Xp3Il/6A9AquiDmP6DCXefnWsAH4J/lviJQ3YuZI37D00d7ziLkZCXPT6ZS5yYTdkFfEvdnKncnl877wE1a7XdEWdUWfLP867NONTh8) - Perl
[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xkQe8f/14) - PCRE2

A trailing newline on the last line is optional. Squares with or without it will both match. (In the 69 byte version, the trailing newline was mandatory.)

In PCRE, acceptance of a trailing newline can be disabled with a flag: [Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xkQe8f/16)
But in Perl, the only way to do this is to replace `$` with `\z` (+1 byte): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJRb6MwDH7Pr7Bo1MVHl6zj@lJKq0rbPe5pj6iItqFFolARpmkQ9td7TunpbnfSWdj@HOzvcxBnXRezy@kDeB1CV1S7tACuQiqjxdP6db3sWVbVgrfRQ7hYhpSn2AFvx@NznZeNF5ceNZs/S26oF3bH6nQOGUCegeAJjMdg3ramIa5k8jCZYqnvRnfYUQeAUZvYKidbQAQ8kQPv@zEvtFgsEbqBjl5ZW6SmCb@MyN8z/UDxS6ogqfsphleV64oghHAtn6B4rXDlvdZveg7e3PuRFkbPPZS0YUSTpKDAKspxSQ8MZtWBTriy6nSY8ATRXT@aOoUeNDFAN@jwJOxZnyTPL09JctkIsYrILRNoJWH5jYk4WPkSEX30WRxwdD0bK30Rz1Y@kz6iRD@eWYlxe7mMgFZtjh/QaNPALjXaMGazqmJ2m9YutFRL5yBdgAEx6xA5s6mz/yY2Avcd/hKR8kbMLMUblu70WjnE7HcyZoMgYPbxkd2QC8S93cm9zuThmDuF9X6fN3lV0r@W/Sv25UbtTw)

The regex does not work in PCRE1 (the older and no longer maintained version of PCRE) due to a PCRE1 bug in which `\2`, a nested backreference, is not reverted to its earlier value when backtracking, causing it to have false positives on shapes that have an equal number of lines as characters in their first line, but whose remaining lines monotonically increase (or stay the same) in length.

In this explanation, `¶` indicates a raw newline in the regex:

```
^                          # Anchor to start of string
(?=                        # Lookahead - allows the same part of the string to
                           # be matched in multiple ways.
    # Assert this is a rectangle (all lines have an equal number of characters)
    # with at least 2 lines. A trailing newline on the last line is optional.
    (
        (?|                # Branch Reset Group - allows the same group numbers
                           # to be captured in different parts of the regex.
            # This alternative is to be taken when the inner loop has reached
            # the end of a line, finishing this iteration of the outer loop.
            ¶
            ()             # \2 = empty, in preparation for the next iteration
                           #      of the outer loop
        |
            # This alternative is to be taken while still processing the line.
            .              # Go forward one character.
            (?=            # Lookahead - match what's inside, then jump back to
                           # this position upon exiting it.
                .*¶        # Skip to the next line
                (          # \2 = the following:
                    \2?+   # Match previous value of \2 if set
                    .      # Match one extra character in this line
                )
            )
        )+                 # Iterate the above as many times as possible
    )+                     # Iterate the above as many times as possible
    ¶                      # Match a newline. Note that the regex engine will
                           # be forced to backtrack, because it will have
                           # already matched this newline inside the loop, and
                           # erased the contents of \2. Backtracking allows it
                           # to undo this, restoring the contents of \2 and
                           # allowing us to match the newline and \2 here.
    \2$                    # Assert that the last line is not longer than the
                           # penultimate line, by asserting that the string
                           # ends after the \2 that was captured. Note that "$"
                           # will match whether this is the end of the string,
                           # or a newline followed by the end of the string.
                           # "\z" only matches at the exact end of the string,
                           # but we don't need to use it.
)
# Assert the number of characters in the first line equals the number of lines
(
    (?=                    # Lookahead
        ^                  # On the leftmost character, match nothing else.
    |                      # On all subsequent characters, do the following:
        .+                 # Skip to the end of this line
        (                  # \4 = the following:
            \4?+           # Match previous value of \4 if set
            ¶.+            # Match a newline, followed by one more entire line,
                           # which we assert is at least one character long.
        )
    )
    .                      # Go forward one character.
)+                         # Iterate the above as many times as possible
\4$                        # Assert that the string ends after \4.

|^.$                       # Or, match a 1×1 square, which the above code can't
                           # do. Again, a trailing newline is optional due to
                           # the behavior of "$".
```

Comment: For my own edification, these regex engines are not "pure" DFA's, and a true regular language (in the computer science sense) couldn't solve this problem -- is that accurate?

Comment: @Jonah That is correct. Lookaheads together with backreferences extend it beyond being a true regular language.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <s>42</s> 39 bytes

Fairly compact, yet easily understandable

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Steffan.

39 bytes solution using Java 8 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxC8IwEIX3/oqjU7tkaJ2EFHR3ci3ItSYSOS4hF0Qq/vaYCoL0DR@87/FkRsLsp7uZE5zQMZhnMnwVOIQAr@qBBHYP5xQd30APcPSeDDLoLHoQRY6NKOsjEjUXJW4xWv/02tocyjURN7aprfcjTxhXLHXbVn@b2vRdych934/cdZvtawtW/c4f)

```scala
s=>s.lines.forall(_.size==s.lines.size)
```

42 bytes solution using Java 11 or newer [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9FowU2T_KSs1OQSBd_EzDyF1IqS1LyUYgXHggKFaq6yxByFNCuF4JKizLx0BVs7Baf8_JzUxDwF26WlJWm6Fje1im3tivVyMvNSi_USc3J8E0uSMzTi9Yozq1JtbWESyfmleSWaUB0JBUCzSnLyNNI0lNLy82PykhKLQESVkqYmF5KcHhrfBAhi8oyNjWPyjIzQ5MCiQAIkXAuxZ8ECCA0A)

```scala
s=>s.lines.allMatch(_.size==s.lines.count)
```

Comment: [By our meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/92689), you can't take input from a variable. You could instead use an anonymous function and prepend `s->`, though.

Comment: noted, thank you @Steffan

Comment: Here's an ATO link for testing this code: [Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9FowU2T_KSs1OQSBd_EzDyF1IqS1LyUYgXHggKFaq6yxByFNCuF4JKizLx0BVs7Baf8_JzUxDwF26WlJWm6Fje1im3tivVyMvNSi_USc3J8E0uSMzTi9Yozq1JtbWESyfmleSWaUB0JBUCzSnLyNNI0lNLy82PykhKLQESVkqYmF5KcHhrfBAhi8oyNjWPyjIzQ5MCiQAIkXAuxZ8ECCA0A)

Comment: Also, this only works in Scala 2 for me, because `lines` returns an `Iterator` instead of a `Stream` in Scala 3. You can save 3 bytes by using Scala 3, though: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxC8IwEIX3/oqjU7tkaJ2EFHR3ci3ItSYSOS4hF0Qq/vaYCoL0DR@87/FkRsLsp7uZE5zQMZhnMnwVOIQAr@qBBHYP5xQd30APcPSeDDLoLHoQRY6NKOsjEjUXJW4xWv/02tocyjURN7aprfcjTxhXLHXbVn@b2vRdych934/cdZvtawtW/c4f "Scala – Try It Online")

Comment: This is interesting. Its not Scala but Java version that is causing the issue, it is the same reason for your shorter solution to be possible.

Scala uses Java types and strings are no exception but they are implicitly converted to `StringOps` class which provides richer API.

Scala first introduced `StringOps.lines` (returns `Iterator`) , however Java 11 added `String.lines` (returns `Stream`).

`forall` is available only if you use `Iterator`. `lines` will implicitly return `Iterator` only if Java version < 11.

@Steffan tio uses Scala 2.10.6, Java 8, ato uses Scala 2.13.8, Java 18

Comment: Ah ok, that's interesting. Fsr I thought TIO ran Scala 3. ATO has Scala 3, but it's broken, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 42 bytes

```julia
!x=(y=split(x,"
");~=length;all(~y.==.~y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3dDoIwDIXv@xRlV1tCmgjekfkixouh/JkpBDCCMbz6bKe3Nvu6c7ac9vrwndstISSL1audBt/NekkVKFNs1lf3Zm4L573eVrKWttWYcHODTlI8giIi@KEAVN33ULqReYmNb4T8jchEywpRhJOCPz0GORdvJp6vk3UgC6Pdc0Ge55BlYkUxcX55pktVU9N2Ck4G3wec2v7JWQgf)

This function splits the string over newlines and checks if the number of lines is equal to the length of each line. Since `length` must be called twice (vectorized and non-vectorized), it is renamed as `~` (Thanks amelies!).

Comment: Not sure this answers the topic question

Comment: @amelies You're right, thanks! I pasted in the solution to a different question by mistake.

Comment: No problems! You can save one byte by replacing \n with a CR

Comment: Renaming `length` you can get to [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY3dCsIwDIXv8xRZr1oYATfvpL6IeNHpfip1G3PCJrJXr0n11tAvPaflJLdn8G63xLjZUPft3B2yxboQ9KZX@xiDn/WSK1DGkLW0rSbe3aizHE@giAh@KADVDANUbmJeYtMbIX8jMsmyQhThpOBPT0HOpZtJ5@tkHcjCZPdcUJYlFIVYUUyaX13oWjfUdl7B2eD7iOPk@zn0HIf4AQ). Very good solution, I doubt I can golf more mine to beat this!

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 39 bytes

```
@.split("
").all((i,j,k)->i.len==k.len)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU69DsIgGNzvKQgTJPgNxRXje5gO2NKIxZYUJl@@8jXGzUvuL7nhhkcYR7/tKVQxuf1KJadYlYTU5FNSKpqnmfXpEimFxbmZTR/zGkodfAlFOHGDnNYVd781vqWBJBbPwB89VoRjSGD95gYAbFzPDbDWouu4cmqUPfIWl6p@L@jls5q03j8)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 58 bytes

```
#(let[s(re-seq #"[^\n]+"%)c count](apply =(c s)(map c s)))
```

Requires a trailing newline, looking forward to seeing something more magical.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

Requires `⎕ML←3` which is default on many systems. Uses CR.

```apl
↓∘⎕FMT≡⎕TC[2]∘≠⊂⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgnG/9OA5KO2yY86ZgDF3HxDHnUuBDJCnKONYkFinQsedTU96lr0/39eDkhl39RQ52AFQ2OuNAX1xKRkdZ28HB31lNQ0CCM9I1Mdp0wWqhRCBwA)

`↓∘⎕FMT` [is the] split-into-lines **F**or**m**a**t**ted-into-a-square argument

`≡` identical to

`⎕TC[2]∘≠` the into-groups-of-non-newline*-characters

`⊂` partitioned

`⊢` argument?

* the second element of the list of **T**erminal **C**ontrol characters.

---

In version 16.0, one can write `↓∘⎕FMT≡⎕TC[3]∘≠⊆⊢` with `⎕ML←1`.

Comment: Curious, what's `⎕ML`?

Comment: @Phoenix In Dyalog APL and APL+, [**M**igration **L**evel](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/ml.htm#kanchor982) is a rough measure for the dialectical movement in direction of IBM's APL2. The higher the number, the more APL2-like does the language become. People migrating from APL2 to other APLs tend to run with a high `⎕ML`, while people who started with the other APLs tend to run with a low `⎕ML`.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 64 bytes

The same (split, line lengths, number of lines) approach as other non-golf language answers, but there's no nice map() equivalent, so it's an array of line lengths with the number of lines tagged onto the end, then that array is grouped. Squares come out like `3,3,3,3 -> 1 group, all line lengths and line count were equal` and non-squares come out like `3,2,1 -> 3 groups`, something was unequal in the square:

```
$f={@(@(($L="$args"-split"`n")|% le*)+$L.Count|group).Count-eq1}
```

Requires newline Linux-style endings, no trailing newline. e.g.

```
$Ttests = @(@'
foo
bar
baz
'@,
'.',
@'
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
'@
)
$Ttests = $Ttests | foreach {$_ -replace "`r"}

$Ttests | % { & $f $_ }
```

(And you can do similar for the false tests, but I won't put it here as there's more of them). The couple of `@` symbols are required for when the input is the single `'.'` otherwise splitting it doesn't make an array of one string it just makes one string, and then the array concatenation doesn't output `1,1` it outputs `2`.

I hoped it might be shorter to replace all the characters with 'a', and then brute force from 1 to Input Length all the squares 'a' and see if any matched the input. Once I got past param() and .Length and -join and -replace it ends up much longer at 81 bytes:

```
$f={param($s)!!(1..$s.Length|?{,('a'*$_)*$_-join"`n"-eq($s-replace"[^`n]",'a')})}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Grime](https://github.com/iatorm/grime), 11 bytes

```
e`.|_./+/.+
```

Prints `1` for squares and `0` for non-squares.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/KzE39/z81Qa8mXk9fW19P@///tPx8rqTEIiCuAgA)

### Explanation

A detailed explanation can be found on the [Grime tutorial page](https://github.com/iatorm/grime/blob/master/tutorial.md#nonterminals), which happens to contain this exact program as an example.

```
e`.|_./+/.+
e`            Match entire input against pattern:
  .           A single character
   |          OR
    _         a recursive match of this pattern
     ./+      with one column of characters on its right
        /     and below that
         .+   one row of characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 73 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>s.Split('\n').All(l=>l.Length==s.Split('\n').Length)
```

Explanation:

```c#
using System.Linq;    //Import Linq
s=>                   //Take input
s.Split('\n')         //Split the input stirng by line feeds
.All(l=>              //Make sure All lines in the array return true for:
l.Length              //The length of the line
==                    //Equaling
s.Split('\n').Length) //The length of the array split again by line feeds
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dart - 54 chars

```dart
q(s)=>!(s=s.split('\n')).any((x)=>x.length!=s.length);
```

(Expects input separated by newlines and not terminated by one)

[Try it online](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b7d68878fb6c12f53ec077c42de45143)

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 42 chars

```
#(every?(fn[x](=(count %)x))(map count %))
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 76 bytes

This should work, next step is trying to golf it more!

```
0v      0   <
 >i:0)?!va=?^1+
:0)?v1n;\~l:   >
    >r:@=?!vr1-^
        ;n0<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36BMAQwMgNiGS8Eu08pA016xLNHWPs5QmwvEKTPMs46py7ECKrDjAim1K7JysAWqKTLUjeNSgALrPAOb//8TExO5oBgA) Or more more fun, try some examples using this [animated interpreter](https://github.com/DuctrTape/fish).

```
printf "aaa\naas\naaa" | fish _square.fish --tick 0.1 --play
```

### Explanation

The idea is roughly as follows.

1. Fill the stack with the number of characters on each line.
2. Push the length of the stack, corresponding to the number of lines (*n*).
3. Do *n* times:

   - Check if bottom two elements are equal.
   - Remove deepest element.

#### Examples

For

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
```

we get `[3, 3, 3, 3]` after the first two steps and we can see that all three length 2 subsequences are equal. However, for

```
aaa
aa
a
```

we get `[3, 2, 1, 3]` and not all sequences are equal. For the last falsy case

```
`abc.def.ghi`
```

we get `[11, 1]` so there is only subpair we can check, but it is unequal so we return falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ａ⁺№θ¶¹αＦ⪪θ¶Ａ×α⁼αＬιαα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU9DW8M5vzSvRKNQR0EpJk9JU0fBEIgTNa250vKLFDSCC3IyEZKaXApAANWppZGoo@BaWJqYUwxi@aTmpZdkaGRqakL1BxRlAs0Fsv7/j1ZSUtJT0OPSU1AAYj0gL/a/btl/3eIcAA) Prints `-` repeated by the side length as truthy, nothing as falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 45 bytes

```
D,g,@,bU10C€=sVcG1+V10CAtbU€bLB]db=$bM*G=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HQScp1NDA@VHTGtvisGR3Q@0wIM@xJCkUKJLk4xSbkmSrkuSr5W4LVJ2RmlOQWqSjpcPFCVQUpqCUlp@vpKCUlFgEJquUFNyzUhSq02sV3FXcVZRs7RSUVDySFdyVdHV1ldw9kmHaTIAAqMPY2BhIGhkRqc1UQSkRBJQUIpJCFUAAmzYuLhWIM/8DAA)

### How it works

Boy this was a long one (not even counting the footer)

```
D,g,@,		; Declare a monadic function 'g'
		; Example argument:    		 ['foo\nbar\nbaz']
	bU	; Unpack;		 STACK = ['f' 'o' 'o' '\n' 'b' 'a' 'r' '\n' 'b' 'a' 'z']
	10C€=s	; Count newlines;	 STACK = ['f' 'o' 'o' '\n' 'b' 'a' 'r' '\n' 'b' 'a' 'z' 2]
	VcG	; Keep last value;	 STACK = [2]
	1+V	; Increment and save;	 STACK = []			; STORE = 3
	10CAt	; Split arg on newlines; STACK = [['foo' 'bar' 'baz']]
	bU€bLB]	; Length of €ach;	 STACK = [[3 3 3]]
	db=	; Are they all equal?	 STACK = [[3 3 3] 1]
	$bM	; Max value;		 STACK = [1 3]
	*	; Logical AND;		 STACK = [3]
	G=	; Equals STORE?		 STACK = [1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLbTsJAEIav26eYbJo00ZII1RsJIgKpRtBEhZggF9PtUqrLtvaAp3jj8/hUvgjO1hOoF8ZtdpJuv/ln/uliECTJYtFxQmfXMYw6dASXmApAmMUKg4jDpFA8j2IFdmibGune4iyRhKRhMRMq3wZahgEjexLHF8rHVId7e2wa/oD4gUqQX9WJOD1rtQ@hoUkb7Ph9XygKPm2knX4/KHWqG@2Xp@dGRmrtuFA5KHEjIyWy@n9FoUayQ@6R4qEQCUjMcpijLMSypIaq60OCDhRPhXYLqALIcL7CjQ09mNOz45Muvbplw61cHyUyyvWkgAb42fRXYjkz3RimZSS35djIrd/bG5NCT6gwn0I8ATpDPl0uO3KBHp0R@A1iW/Tj8qm4A5QSxHWBsvmThirxlt8nvo@3H56XuCpBprGma8dhxFFC66izQujvni7Y1TWyN@PNFY0x3ampkIlInTWnnMcQGHllwMhrGe8ZeJcBPISP4FmexRo7wKx9Dh6rVCrM2@cfaZu0KMN1XYq12h/TtoChXgzO/YG@or@mmab11ubiFQ)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 65 bytes

```php
while(~$c=$argv[1][$p++])$w+=":"^$c||$w=!$$w+=!!++$h;echo$$h==$h;
```

expects linux style line endings (`\n`) and a trailing newline; prints `1` for truthy, nothing for falsy.
Run with `php -nr '<code>' '<input>'` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb1702f524caa15e83c030593d304f5bdff07d63).

---

Btw: The naive approach takes 82 bytes:

```php
<?=count($a=explode("
",$argv[1]))==min($m=array_map(strlen,$a))&min($m)==max($m);
```

expects linebreaks as on compile system and no trailing newline; prints `1` or `0`.
Run with `php -nR '<code>' '<input>'`.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3, 79 bytes**

```
lambda a:len(set([len(list(i))for i in a.split('\n')]+[len(a.split('\n'))]))==1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 3](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), 134 bytes

```
import Foundation;func r(s:String)->Bool{let i=s.components(separatedBy:"\n");return i.filter{$0.characters.count != i.count}.isEmpty}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/ARR85441)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>76</del> 61 bytes

```
Fn.new{|a|a.split("\n").all{|x|x.count==a.split("\n").count}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xg@98tTy8vtby6JrEmUa@4ICezREMpJk9JUy8xJ6e6pqKmQi85vzSvxNYWVRYsWFv7P7iyuCQ1V6@gKDOvRANkol4yUKOGUmJiYkwejEhU0tT8DwA)

### Old answer

The algorithm is essentially just copied from a 05AB1E answer.

```
Fn.new{|a|
var b=a.split("\n").map{|i|i.count}
return b.all{|i|i==b.count}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY0xCsMwDEX3nMJ4shfdwGsv0DWLbFQwOGpQ5JoS5@xOU8jyhv8@vCbE44NiXpWTCePBwNT2jn261hgQtrVkdXZm62HBde@5Z0jvynpMQlqFTQQs5S9CiLc7xvO7KS3QJCu5KwDp93MWEWe@Yb0fJw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 73 bytes

```
func[s][all collect[foreach b a: split s lf[keep(length? b)= length? a]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xCsMwDEV3nUJkahcNSadA6R26Gg@2IyehJg6OuzTk7K4zpDWFCn2h//hIgbt0505IsG2yz8mIRQrlHBrvHJsorA@szIAaVYvL7MaICzorHszzyfHUx@GG@nzFY1dSyjSHcYpocbXeg1Yh67XBQSuqPvtKSECIWfRNrBkgFl7tBX9mkaN87MfuXaBLLmiaBuq6oDvIKj9qQx1b6odxS28)

`{abcd
efg}`  represents true multiline string and not a list of strings, hence I need `split s lf`

Answer (score 1):

## [SnakeEx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47555/16766), 38 bytes

```
h:{c<B>1}{c<L>1}{e<>}{e<R>}
c:.+$
e:.$
```

A match is truthy; no match is falsey. [**Try it here**](http://www.brianmacintosh.com/snakeex/)

---

The previous [50-byte SnakeEx submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124969/16766) was copied from the original solution to the detect-square-inputs problem in the 2D pattern-matching language challenge. Here's the thing: that problem says, "*Match the entire input* if it is a square block of characters." But for this problem, we merely need to match *something* if the input is a square block of characters. That enables us to use a different approach, saving bytes.

Instead of matching the whole square, we match its bottom row and rightmost column and assert that they are the same length. (It's important to pick the rightmost column, since that will fail if we have jagged input.)

- `c:.+$` Define `c` to match some number of characters and then the edge of the grid
- `e:.$` Define `e` to match the character it's currently on and then the edge of the grid
- `{c<B>1}` Turn backwards (i.e. toward the left side), match `c`, and put that match in group 1
- `{c<L>1}` Turn left (i.e. toward the top), match `c`, and put that match in group 1 (thereby requiring both matches to be the same length)
- `{e<>}` Match `e` in the default direction (toward the right side)
- `{e<R>}` Turn right (i.e. toward the bottom) and match `e`

The two `c` calls make sure the height and width are the same; the two `e` calls make sure our starting point is the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 47

Closing parens/quotes already discounted.

Input: `A1`

`A2` to `A3`:

```
=ArrayFormula(LEN(SPLIT(A1,"
")))
=A2=COUNTIF(2:2,A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.B¤g∍»Q
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@nQkvRHHb2Hdgf@/6@kpGRoZMyVmJTMZa5nDOQBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpeRfWgLh2Ve6/NdzOrQk/VFH76Hdgf91Dm2z/x@tlJafH5OXlFgEIqqUdBSU9MCEgl5Mnp6CAogAC4CYCkAjlRJBICYPNwVSbWhkHJMHI@ACiUnJMXnmemABPZD5YEZMHoiC8fRAEiAIYoFETIAgJs/YGKjfyAgkAGYCCRAbaKJeSmqaXnpGplIsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.B       # Box the (implicit) multi-line input-string, splitting on newlines,
         # and appended spaces to make all rows the same length
  ¤      # Push the last string (without popping the list)
   g     # † Pop and push its length
    ∍    # Extend/shorten the list up to this length
     »   # Join it by newlines
      Q  # Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† This is only necessary if the last line of the input is a number. Builtin `∍` will extend/shorten it to the number size if a number is given as argument, but will use the length to extend/shorten if a string is given. E.g. [`"ab" "abcdefg" ∍` will extend the `"ab"` to `length("abcdefg")=7`, resulting in `"abababa"`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTFJSQFIJKekpqUrKTzq6P3/HwA), but unfortunately [`"123" "12" ∍` will extend the `"123"` to `"123123123123"`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fydDIWEkBSCopPOro/f8fAA) instead of shortening it to `length("12")=2` to `"12"`.
So for all given test cases `.B¤∍»Q` would have sufficed, but unfortunately it'll fail for something like [`123\nabc\n7.3`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz@nQkkcdvYd2//@vpKRkaGTMlZiUzGWuZwzkAQA).

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 15 bytes

```
>∘⊔'
'⊸(≠×1+`=)
```

Anonymous tacit function. Takes a multiline string that must include a trailing newline. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgPuKImOKKlCcKJ+KKuCjiiaDDlzErYD0pCgpzcXVhcmUg4oaQICJhYmMKZGVmCiAgIAoiCnJlY3RhbmdsZSDihpAgImFiYwpkZWYKIgpyYWdnZWQg4oaQICJhYmMKZGUKZmdoCiIKCkbijooiRVJST1Iiwqggc3F1YXJl4oC/cmVjdGFuZ2xl4oC/cmFnZ2Vk)

Outputs via error for falsey and no error for truthy. If that's not acceptable, here's a 19-byte version that returns 0 for falsey and 1 for truthy:

```
≡·>⎊0·⊔'
'⊸(≠×1+`=)
```

#### Explanation

```
>∘⊔'¶'⊸(≠×1+`=)
       (      )   Call this function with the multiline string as right argument
   '¶'⊸           and a newline character as left argument:
             =      For each character in the string, 1 if it is newline, 0 otherwise
           +`       Cumulative sum of that array
          1         starting at 1
         ×          For each of those values, multiply by the corresponding value in:
        ≠           For each character in the string, 0 if it is newline, 1 otherwise
                  This transforms the first line into 1s, the second line into 2s, etc.,
                  and newlines into 0s
  ⊔               Group the indices of this list according to their values in the list
>∘                Attempt to convert that list of lists to a rectangular array
```

- If not all lines in the input are the same length, the groups will have different lengths, and the conversion to an array will fail.
- If the input is rectangular but not square, the newlines group will have a different length from the other groups, and the conversion will fail.
- If the input is an N by N square, there will be a group representing N newlines and N groups representing N characters each, which will be successfully converted into an N+1 by N array.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 10 or 8 bytes

```
(≢=(⌈/≢¨))
```

Input is an array of strings.

Explained:

```
(       ) fork (could be removed if assigned to a variable)
 ≢        amount of strings
  =       equals
   (⌈/ )  the maximum
     ≢¨   of each of the string's lengths
```

Comment: "Input is a string or 1D char array; it is not a list of strings."

Comment: But that's the closest i can get, i don't how to type new line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>44</s> 41 bytes

```julia
!s=(l=count(==('
'),s)+1)l==length(s)-l+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYdLDkAwFAD37xTVjTZoUl0/FxELEfHJS6lWWLh7ERYzmZl3mlp9xph4FITdstsgEEUKqcy9zLQkROrtEEbhZUGZjiqpuS4NuKPnOXBjDPy865wDePS2YgzYB2/UVa3bZAPZeAM)

Answer (score 0):

## SnakeEx, 50 bytes

This is [BMac's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47555/34718) to the problem for the 2D regex language design challenge.

```
m:{v<R>1}{h<>1}
v:${c<L>A1}+$
h:${c<R>A1}+$
c:$.+$
```

[**Try it online**](http://www.brianmacintosh.com/snakeex/)

Answer (score 0):

## J, 12 bytes

```
(*./=#)#;._2
```

Input requires trailing LF or CR.

Explanation:

- `;._2` split into [intervals](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/semidot1#dyadic) and discard trailing atom
- `#` [count](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/number) each group
- `(*./=#)` is a [fork](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/fork) which returns 0 (false) or 1 (true) if the [LCM](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/stardot#dyadic) of the count of each group is [equal](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/eq#dyadic) to the count-of-counts

Tests

```
(*./=#)#;._2 'abc', LF, 'def', LF, 'ghi', LF   NB. 1 for well-formed input
(*./=#)#;._2 'abc', LF, 'def', LF, 'ghi'       NB. 0 because no trailing LF
```

Comment: How does it determine what the delimiter is..? And by the way, `abc.def.ghi.` should be falsy, so while clever, the delimiter trick is actually invalid.

Comment: @Phoenix A test case to reflect that would be beneficial

Comment: @Phoenix My answer used to just say "requires trailing delimiter" but I edited it to specifically call out either LF or CR.


`abc.def.ghi.` would be truthy but `abc.def.ghi.LF` (trailing LF) would be falsy.

Comment: abc.def.ghi. Is not a square string and should not be accepted.

Comment: The way I read the rules, since I can require that all inputs end in LF, then my program should never have the chance to either accept or reject inputs which don't end in LF.

Comment: 15 Bytes for `*/(=#)#@>@cutLF`, which only accepts LF as a delimiter, and does not require a trailing LF: `*/(=#)#@>@cutLF 'abc', LF, 'def', LF, 'ghi'` returns 1

Comment: This fails by returning true if the row counts are, eg, `4 2 4 4`.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600tPT0bZU1la314o3@a3L5OekpAAV1rar1lKv1IMJcqckZ@QppIK0GXHpAwAVGMELzPwA "J – Try It Online").  The function `[:(-:{.#{.)#;._2` works.

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 7 bytes

```
ln)L[sm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f8/J0/TJ7o49/9/PQU9Lj0FBS4QDQA)

Requires a trailing newline after the input. Technically the trailing newline is only needed if the input ends on a newline (as `ln` ignores one trailing newline), and it doesn't make a difference whether it's there or not otherwise, but stating it as a blanket requirement is probably preferable. Returns 1 for square inputs and 0 otherwise.

Explanation:

```
ln       # Split input string into lines
  )      # Map each line...
   L[    # ...to its length
     sm  # Are all line lengths the same?
```

Comment: This is checking that the input is a rectangle, but not that it is a square. You need to also check that the length of a line is the same as the number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.matrices`, 28 bytes

```factor
[ "\n"split square-matrix? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZC9DsIgFIV3nuKGXYbWSQdH4@JinMSBVtqS2FsKNPEnPjtCC4mLZziX84WcG2hE7Qbjz6fDcb@BXriOBTOqlha0kc49tVHowMpxkhip1XflnMIWtoS8CQTRZhg4VsJEe9GFsTyBcWQA0TKLKYwliCiO/wclqSkW5VaO6fTDWLwRclBC6yCOZVlyLIrE5hQsr69qdpMNaztFycdfYiOdHwl2nISRq/lDHju4@l5oYP4L)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 40 bytes

```sh
set -- "${(@f)1}"
for l;(($#l==$#))||bye
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BCoMwEEX3nuKjAWcoLqJdVaQ9iJsWIhUkrUkKbdWzp4klmz@fecPwvvbuR2vn19UoYrLKoXr7fVTIxUKXgeWWZ8PDYGqJRDF1nSiY1/X2UZ534JR1oEyUsoxR97o5xgag1ykSknWT6v@O2yUDkgRE/BYWTzPqYGGCxfmEYDIfOKIgs/kf)

---

Using modern [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem) rules, we can save **1 byte** by swapping truthy and falsy:

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 39 bytes

```sh
set -- "${(@f)1}"
for l;(($#l-$#))&&bye
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETv@YpFg@5Scoj2VA/th3hpIVJBYs2m0Fb89jSxBHqZGWaW5X34Hka2s@fleXUGCdl4UK@wm4JCrngZSG@FGGYHU4coy0nJkqiqbm8TaO@9YQ8oZK3rJE1v22NKANDbLHnSTZvj7466VQD8YYBMD2P3cKONHC5ynE8QWZYDpSnibOEL)

```sh
set -- "${(@f)1}"    # (f) splits into lines, (@) and "" are needed to preserve empty lines
for l                # for each line:
   (($#l-$#))&&bye   # - if the line length differs from the number of lines, exit 0.
                     # otherwise, ((0)) from the last loop iteration has an exit code of 1,
                     # so we exit 1.
```